# elastic strings and springs mechanics problem.

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

This is an example given in Edexcel M3. In question below  **length =1m and λ=10N** but the given answer(Circled in red) it looks like the value of λ multiplied by 2. I couldn't figure it out why? Need Help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I find the referenced problem quite puzzling. First, it references the modulus of elasticity as 10 newtons, but such a modulus is typically defined as a stress-strain ratio and thus has units of force per unit area (N/m^2). (The lack of units overall in the solution is rather disturbing as well...) Second, the elastic PE is given by $\frac12 k x^2$ where $k$ is the stiffness (units of N/m) and while this can be related to the modulus it's not identical to it. Lastly, as you noticed it _somehow_ concludes that $k=20$ N/m, and there appears no motivation for this. So...I dunno.

Comment: maybe a printing mistake in the question. Modulus of elasticity should be 20N not 10N I think.

Comment: This question might be better suited for Physics.SE (physics.stackexchange.com)